# How does foreach traverse array?

Tags: php, arrays

From what I have found `foreach` traverses array in the order of adding elements. See this code:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = "me0";
$array[1] = "me1";
$array[2] = "me2";
$array[4] = "me4";
$array[5] = "me5";

//changing
$array[3] = "me3Changed";

foreach($array as $item)
{
    echo $item.'<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
ksort($array);

foreach($array as $item)
{
    echo $item.'<br />';
}
```

which outputs:

```
me0
me1
me2
me4
me5
me3Changed

me0
me1
me2
me3Changed
me4
me5
```

This shows that the array is not traversed in a way `for($i;$i<$arrayLength;$i++)`
how is it traversed than? Assuming that php is written in C++ it should be using some c++ functions that do it this way. **Can anyone explain to me how does `foreach` traverse arrays?**

---

C++ example of traversing array by index:

```
std::string arr[10]; 
arr[0] = "me0";
arr[1] = "me1";
arr[2] = "me2";
arr[4] = "me4";
arr[5] = "me5";

//changing
arr[3] = "me3Changed";

for(int x = 0; x < 6;x++)
{
    std::cout << arr[x] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Trying to rationalise PHP's behaviour in terms of what may or may not be its underlying implementation in some other language is a fool's errand.

Comment: relevant to understanding foreach's order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487374/does-php-conserver-order-in-associative-array/11487417#11487417

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP arrays are *ordered* key-value stores. Meaning the keys have an order, which is the order in which they were added to the array (or spliced together or sorted or whatever determined the order). `foreach` traverses arrays in this inherent, built-in order.

I don't know if this compares to anything in C. PHP's arrays are one of its more unique features. Most languages have key-value stores (dictionaries/hashes) *or* ordered arrays (lists). PHP has *ordered key-value stores* as its only array type.

Answer (score 0):

The array is formed as you add in the key/value pair, look [here](http://codepad.org/3XxcUwUR). Hence, `foreach` traverses in that order as well.

Whereas, you are comparing it with a loop `for($i;$i<$arrayLength;$i++)` where you are specifying the `index`, hence, its ALWAYS going to search for that key, and then print its corresponding value.

**Edit:** [Example](http://codepad.org/qH7jLJ9W) explaining the above.

Comment: Can you explain it to me by writing a simple foreach function either in PHP or C++?