# Equivalent for LinkedHashMap in php?

Tags: java, php, phpexcel, linkedhashmap

My application is currently on java and I am sending a LinkedHashMap (getting Data from Excel) to a service. Now I am converting my application to php.

I need to create a LinkedHashMap in php.

```
String data[][];  // Excel data in the form of 2-D Array.
LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList> mapToSend = null;
mapToSend = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList>();


for (int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRecords; j++) {
        if (data[j][i] != null) {
             data[j][i] = data[j][i].toString();

            ar.add(data[j][i]); // Add in array through coloumnwise
            } else {
            ar.add("Empty");
        }
    }
    mapToSend.put(i, ar); // making a map like {0=[coloumn data1],1=[coloumn data2]....}
}
```

This is how I create the map to sent to my service.

I am using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to read data from Excel.

i need to create a map and send it to a service. please Suggest.

Comment: I doubt that you send the actual `LinkedHashMap` using serialization. So how should the map be represented, and what have you tried to create such a representation using PHP?

Comment: what about using JSON instead as an intermediate format?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Map should be represented as {0=[coloumn data1],1=[coloumn data2]....}

Comment: You mean the `toString()` output of the map in Java? Ugh, OK. Please edit essential information such as in the comment above into the question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes no,  I told you the format which i am sending to a service which manipulate this Map.

Comment: @AbdoAdel- JSON a better option indeed, but Its not possible for me to change the code in Services side.

Comment: For goodness sake, please clearly *explain in the question* the exact *format of the data*. Show what you have done to try and replicate this in PHP.

Comment: I have my doubts about what the questioner really is after, but I want to point out: A linked hash map in PHP is simply an associative array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914730/are-php-associative-arrays-ordered

Comment: @fjf2002 But I dont think it work like a key value pair. I can only identify on the basis of Index.

Comment: @Mishra Shreyanshu: You are wrong. (A) An associative array by definition stores key-value-pairs. (B) In in the case of PHP, an order is guaranteed - which is what Javas' LinkedHashMap distinguishes from an ordinary (Java) Map.

Comment: @fjf2002: I tried,Thats worked for me. I was started working on JSON format. Now there's some hope with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided actually looks more like a 'normal' array in PHP. Arrays in PHP can act as *arrays in the more traditional sense*, *maps like your Java one* (except they still possess order over and above that implied by the keys themselves).

Your implementation looks like the below in PHP. There's a number of assumptions about the data input and required business logic there, I would write some test cases that define cases such as 'true', 0, '' against the required output. Basically, watch out for all the ways `strval($data[$j][$i])` can behave differently.

You are creating a map from integer => string in Java, but to me it just looks like an normal array.

```
$data = array();

//the input data
$data[] = array("val1", "val2");
$data[] = array("val3", 0);
$data[] = array("val4");
$data[] = array("val5", "");
$data[] = array(0, "val6");

$numberOfRecords = count($data); //assuming all of it...

$mapToSend = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($data[0]); $i++) {
        $ar = array();
        for($j = 0; $j < $numberOfRecords; $j++) {
                if( ($val = strval($data[$j][$i])) != "" ) {//the comparison of your choice, depending on the logic/input
                        $ar[] = $val;
                } else {
                        $ar[] = "Empty";
                }
        }
        $mapToSend[] = $ar; //naturally, this will have indexes 0, 1, 2...
}

var_dump( $mapToSend );
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "val3"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "val4"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "val5"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Empty"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Empty"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "val6"
  }
}
```