# Find an entire object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I find **Array2** in **Array1** . I have been using **$.inArray()** method or **indexOf()** but it return false yet the statement is true.

```
var array1 = [{
    h: 1480508328,
    rid: 16,
    sid: 2
  }, {
    h: 87542,
    rid: 18,
    sid: 9
  }
];
var array2 = {
  h: 1480508328,
  rid: 16,
  sid: 2
};
//test if array2 exist in array1
if ($.inArray(array2, array1) > 0) {
  console.log('Object is in array');
} else {
  console.log('Object is not in array');
}
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: FYI, `array2` is not an array. It's an object. `array2` is also not in `array1`, only an object which *looks* like `array2`. So you'll have to [iterate over `array1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and check if any item matches `array2`.

Comment: but var array1 is an associative array (value pare) .... isn't it?

Comment: well.... no. [To quote](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp): "JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes. In JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes. "*

Comment: @jamesOduro In a way you could say that but we don't call them associative arrays in JS since there's no guarantees on order. They're called objects.

Comment: Javascript is weird, is what we're saying

Comment: okay... I guess am bring the idea of PHP ASSOCIATIVE ARRAYS.  I always assume javascript object as associative array since they are value/pair ....anyway thanks for explanation

Comment: Well, funny you should mention that. See, in PHP, associative arrays aren't that either. They're actually [ordered maps optimized to be used as arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914745/2387772).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate the array and check the length of the properties with the length of the given object and check every value.

```js
var array = [{ h: 1480508328, rid: 16, sid: 2 }, { h: 87542, rid: 18, sid: 9 }],
    object = { h: 1480508328, rid: 16, sid: 2 },
    found = array.some(function (a) {
        var keys = Object.keys(a);
        return keys.length === Object.keys(object).length && keys.every(function (k) {
            return a[k] === object[k];
        });
    });
  
console.log(found);
```

```js
var array = [{ h: 87542, rid: 18, sid: 9 }, { h: 1480508328, rid: 16, sid: 2 }],
    object = { h: 1480508328, rid: 16, sid: 2 },
    found = array.some(function (a) {
        var keys = Object.keys(a);
        return keys.length === Object.keys(object).length && keys.every(function (k) {
            return a[k] === object[k];
        });
    });
  
console.log(found);
```

Comment: I think your answer is the best solution

Comment: The answer yuvi provided has a big problem if  the sorting is not the same.. An element could be found at position 1 and not in position 0

Comment: So how do I return the position of the item found ?

Comment: @jamesOduro, it does not matter, because all elements of the array are checked. please see edit with reversed items.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.prototype.every` to check if *each* object property of the array and the object matches - now use `Array.prototype.some` to check if at least once the object exists inside the array.

See demo below:

```js
var array1=[{h:1480508328,rid:16,sid:2},{h:87542,rid:18,sid:9}];
var object={h:1480508328,rid:16,sid:2}

var result = array1.some(function(e){
  return Object.keys(object).length === Object.keys(e).length && Object.keys(e).every(function(k){
    return k in object && e[k] === object[k];
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is the object property...do you mean the 'key'??

Comment: `object` is the same as your `array2`

Comment: @james Oduro Objects have properties and arrays have keys which are also properties since an array is an object in JS. Yet arrays may also have properties which are not keys. It's best to think it like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify it and check for equality

```
var array1 = [{
    h: 1480508328,
    rid: 16,
    sid: 2
  }, {
    h: 87542,
    rid: 18,
    sid: 9
  }
];
var array2 = {
  h: 1480508328,
  rid: 16,
  sid: 2
};

var dat1 = JSON.stringify(array2);
array1.forEach(function(item){
    if(JSON.stringify(item) === dat1){
        console.log(dat1)
    } else {
        console.log('Not match')
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2s9m5kbr/)

Comment: Note: It might be a problem if object's attributes are differently sorted.

Comment: for some reason to help my project I choose yours as the answer

Comment: Thank you so much.