# Why does Symfony provide an OrderedHashMap

Tags: php, symfony, associative-array, symfony3.x, ordered-map

Symfony provides an `OrderedHashMap`. Its [documentation states](https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/OrderedHashMap.html)

> Unlike associative arrays, the map keeps track of the order in which keys were added and removed. This order is reflected during iteration.

I'm confused by this statement, because I thought PHP associative arrays are actually already ordered maps. I found this question on SO, which confirms my previous assumption: [Are PHP Associative Arrays ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10914730/395879)

I wonder, if the Symfony devs didn't know PHP arrays are already ordered maps or if I don't understand the role of Symfony's `OrderedHashMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course PHP's array is an ordered-map.

But Symfony's `OrderedHashMap` has some different behaviors (say, *features*) from PHP's array.

`OrderedHashMap` supports concurrent modification during iteration. That means that you can insert and remove elements from within a `foreach` loop and the iterator will reflect those changes accordingly. But `array` in the iteration is a copied one (*Copy-On-Write*), any modification is not reflected in the loop.

```
$map = new OrderedHashMap();
$map[1] = 1;
$map[2] = 2;
$map[3] = 3;

foreach ($map as $index => $value) {
    echo "$index: $value\n"
    if (1 === $index) {
        $map[1] = 4;
        $map[] = 5;
    }
}
```

You will get different output if you are using `array`. In the iteration of an `array` the loop won't see the number `5`.

About "*Why?*": Search it in [Symfony's codebase](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Asymfony+OrderedHashMap&type=Code). There is only **one** place to use the `OrderedHashMap`, which is used to store a form's children. It's used by `new InheritDataAwareIterator($this->children)` to iterate. So I think the answer is to help to process the form's children.

And thanks to @fishbone:

> So the benefit is not the ordering but the ability to modify it in loops.

Comment: This doesn't explain why they say that associative arrays don't keep track of the order. So the benefit is not the ordering but the ability to modify it in loops

Answer (score 0):

In general, not only in Symfony's context, beside additional implemented features, object oriented structures are preferred over primitive types such as `int`, `string` or `array` as they can be injected into the class for unit testing.

Object oriented structures can enforce invariants as well whereas primitive types can only hold data without any behaviors.

Comment: It is not true, because php's array is implemented by Copy-On-Write. Passing arrays is as light as passing objects.

Comment: So try to modify and return that array from 10 different places.

Comment: Please see my comment to shawn's answer

Comment: There is only a few usages of OrderedHashMap in Symfony's codebase: https://github.com/symfony/form/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=OrderedHashMap&type=  The `children` is already `private`, no chance to trigger COW by different places.

Comment: What's a real world usage of passing an argument and doing nothing with it?

Comment: Reading an array doesn't trigger COW. Passing an argument and reading it, very common.